# How to translate multiple words simultaneously in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, substitution

I'm attempting to create a substitution translator for a language my friend and I created. In this language, certain things have to happen simultaneously and I can't figure out how to do that in Ruby.

With simple things like swapping the vowels around, i.e.

```
a --> u
i --> o
o --> i
u --> a
```

I've just done this:

```
input.tr("aiou", "uoia")
```

But I can't figure out a way to make the following translations occur simultaneously:

```
no --> e
e --> y
y --> el
```

so that the phrase "yellow rhino" would become "elyllow rhie".

Any suggestions or examples for what I can do? `gsub`? `tr`? Another method altogether?

Comment: Though not the most direct approach, you actually could use [String#tr](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-tr) here. Starting with @tadman's hash `MAP`, one could write `g={"no"=>128.chr, "el"=>129.chr}; gi=g.invert; s1,s2 = MAP.to_a.transpose.map{ |a| a.map {|s| g.fetch(s, s)}.join}; "ienoay".tr(s1, s2).each_char.map {|s| gi.fetch(s, s)}.join #=> "oyniuel"`. Here `s1 #=> "aioue\x80y"; s2
 #=> "uoiaye\x81"`. See [Hash#fetch](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html), quite a useful method. Just sayin'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you define a substitution map:

```
MAP = {
  'a' => 'u',
  'i' => 'o',
  'o' => 'i',
  'u' => 'a',
  'y' => 'el',
  'no' => 'e',
  'e' => 'y'
}
```

Then you can make this into a regular expression to match all the "keys" in one shot:

```
SUBST = Regexp.union(MAP.keys)
```

This is handy because [`gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) can use these mapping tables to do substitution:

```
def translate(words)
  words.gsub(SUBST, MAP)
end
```

Which means you can do this:

```
puts translate("translate multiple words simultaneously")
# => trunsluty maltoply wirds somaltunyiaslel
```

`tr` is a great tool, but it's limited to single character substitutions. `gsub` can do everything `tr` can and more.

Comment: @kaolincash The Stack Overflow way to express your thanks is to _accept_ this answer (click the checkmark at the left so it turns green).

Comment: @matt There's usually a waiting period for new users before they can accept it. Rules are different for <100 rep.

Comment: @tadman Yes, I don't mean to speak for you, just making sure the OP knows about this, as new users often do not. By the way, awesome answer; I had no idea about this. One wonders: "how long has _this_ been going on"? :)

Comment: Just have to be careful about how you build the "map" in this case so that you don't end up with premature matches like say `{ "o" => "i", "oh" => "no"}`

Comment: @engineersmnky that's a very good point. The matches should either be non-overlapping on the first letter, or ordered from longest to shortest. This could be done in a pre-Regexp pass with `sort_by`.

Comment: @matt The `gsub(pattern, hash)` variant of `gsub` has been around since at least [Ruby 1.9](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub), so presumably since about 2007.